# Is it GOOD to put Custom Dialog inside the base fragment android Kotlin w.r.t performance, etc

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm creating custom dialog in some Fragments but I came up with a base fragment to use there and then just call from CHILD Fragment.

For instance, I've 10 fragments out of which just 3 are using that.

Does it good to move dialogs with base fragment and I just no need to recreate it.

> **Anything that affects here will be good to know for me**

like cohesion, coupling, performance, architecture, etc

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an opinion-based subject. But I think "composition over inheritance" is pretty universally accepted advice in the OOP world.

What you're doing doesn't matter one way or the other with respect to performance, but it's kind of a bad solution for code maintainability.

Some relevant things to read:

- [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)
- [Android Nightmares  | Base classes](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/android-nightmares-base-classes-ccf55dbd0604)
- [Say no to BaseActivity and BaseFragment](https://proandroiddev.com/say-no-to-baseactivity-and-basefragment-83b156ed8998)
- [BaseActivity and BaseFragment are monsters](https://proandroiddev.com/baseactivity-and-basefragment-are-monsters-5cda31639938)

To do this without inheritance in this case, you can make a top-level extension function with the relevant arguments that returns the dialog. Example:

```
fun Fragment.showANumberDialog(theNumber: Int): AlertDialog =
    AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        .setTitle(theNumber.toString())
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) {}
        .show()
```

Note: You should really be using DialogFragment instead of a bare Dialog so it is maintained after screen rotations and when returning to the app after it has been in the background for a while. So the above example more appropriately would look like this:

```
fun Fragment.showANumberDialog(theNumber: Int) =
    ANumberDialogFragment().apply {
        arguments = bundleOf(NUM_KEY to theNumber.toString())
        show(childFragmentManager, ANumberDialogFragment.TAG)
    }

private const val NUM_KEY = "the number"

class ANumberDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog =
        AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setTitle(arguments.getString(NUM_KEY))
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok) {}
            .show()

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "ANumberDialogFragment"
    }
}
```