# Android : Kotlin Initialise interface variable and call its method

Tags: android, kotlin, class, oop, interface

I have a base activity which observes the change of network connectivity status.

```
    class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val connectivityLiveStatus: ConnectionLiveStatus = ConnectionLiveStatus(this)

    init {
        observeConnectivity()
    }

    private fun observeConnectivity(){
        connectivityLiveStatus.observe(this , Observer {status ->
             handleConnectivityStatus()  
        })
    }
    private fun handleConnectivityStatus(){} 
}
```

I want my MainActivity to inherit this BaseActivity class and have its own definition of handling change in connectivity.

But since MainActivity already inherits AppCompatActivity()

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var movieViewModel : MoviesViewModel
lateinit var moviesAdapter : MoviesAdapter
lateinit var movieRecyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var connectivityLiveStatus: ConnectionLiveStatus
private var pageAlreadyLoaded = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    init()

}
```

I cannot Inherit another Class since Kotlin does not allow multiple Inheritence.

So I created an Interface called BaseActivityListener.

```
interface BaseActivityListener {
    fun handleNetworkConnectivityChange(status : Boolean)
}
```

And inherited this interface in the MainActivity to have its own definition for handling Network Connectivity changes.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , BaseActivityListener {

lateinit var movieViewModel : MoviesViewModel
lateinit var moviesAdapter : MoviesAdapter
lateinit var movieRecyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var connectivityLiveStatus: ConnectionLiveStatus
private var pageAlreadyLoaded = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    init()

}

override fun handleNetworkConnectivityChange(status: Boolean) {
    TODO("handle network connectivity change")
}
```

But Since the Network Connectivity changing status is only available in the BaseActivity ,
I want to invoke the method handleNetworkConnectivityChange() of interface from the BaseActivity itself.

But I am Unable to create an object of this interface in BaseActivity using Kotlin, Which would have been done easily using the new operator in Java.
[image]

How to initialise an interface Object in Kotlin ?
I understand using interface makes it tight coupling , Is there any other way to do in this situation ?

Comment: Instructions for creating an anonymous implementation of an interface are [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#creating-anonymous-objects-from-scratch). Also, you must not put code in an `init` block of an Activity subclass that does anything involving any properties or functions of Activity (because it will not be set up yet at this stage of the class initialization). Move that to `onCreate()`. You can’t call your `init` block like a function. That doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Since `BaseActivity` inherits from `AppCompatActivity`, you can make `MainActivity` inherit from `BaseActivity` and it'll still be a subclass of `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Also, you might want to read the links I posted here before you decide to use a BaseActivity class. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72994918/506796

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks a lot for all the resources , thank you so much Ill go through it to understand more. I did not understand your point related to init() , init() is just a function that i created to initialise all the varialbles.

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks a lot , I did not think of it that way . But since my implementation seems to be inefficient I might change the whole BaseActivity thing. Thanks again tho.

Comment: I thought you were trying to call your `init` block, not function. Just ignore that point.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yeaah I understood that . Anyway thanks a lot