# Inherit kotlin object from raw-type java object implicitly using upper bound

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, inheritance, raw-types

I have:

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity { ... }
```

and i want to change it like this:

```
class BaseActivity<T extends BaseActivity<T>> { ... }
```

but i dont want to change all files in project

and in Java i can do:

```
class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity { ... }
```

yes i will get "Raw use of parameterized class 'BaseActivity'" warning but
in kotlin i have to explicitly write a type:

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity<HomeActivity>() { ... }
```

or error will be "One type argument expected for class BaseActivity<T : BaseActivity<*>!>"

is there any option to make it work?

Comment: Create a `GenericBaseActivity` class, and have all the classes you want to be generic extend that.

Comment: A warning about BaseActivities: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72994918/506796

Comment: No, Kotlin won't let you use raw types. Which they can do because it's been a language feature from the beginning. Java only allowed it because they had to, for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

This trick is to allow the superclass to use the type of subclass.

For example, you could define fields/methods in `BaseActivity<T>` as

```java
  List<T> siblings;
  void addSibling(T sibling);
```

then in your subclass `HomeActivity` which extends from `BaseActivity<HomeActivity>` will have typed members from the superclass,

```java
  List<HomeActivity> siblings;
  void addSibling(HomeActivity sibling);
```

Using raw type causes the loss of types of these members.